# How to put dynamic array in function C#?

Tags: arrays, function, dynamic

This my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class RetardedStudent
    {
        public String Name = "1";
        public int IQ;
        public void PrintName()
        {
            Console.Write("Student Name ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write(Name);
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.Write(" Student Test Result: ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write(IQ);
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public unsafe void SortRetardedStudents(RetardedStudent[] Retards)
        {
            int IQ;
            string Name;
            int RetardsNumber = Retards.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < RetardsNumber; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < RetardsNumber - i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (Retards[j].IQ > Retards[j + 1].IQ || (Retards[j].IQ == Retards[j + 1].IQ) && (String.Compare(Retards[j].Name, 0, Retards[j + 1].Name, 0, Math.Max(Retards[j].Name.Length, Retards[j + 1].Name.Length)) > 0))
                    {
                        IQ = Retards[j].IQ;
                        Name = Retards[j].Name;
                        Retards[j].IQ = Retards[j + 1].IQ;
                        Retards[j].Name = Retards[j + 1].Name;
                        Retards[j + 1].IQ = IQ;
                        Retards[j + 1].Name = Name;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                Console.Write("Input number of students:");
                Console.WriteLine();
                int RetardsNumber;// = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//Convert не прокатывает если ввести не число
                Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out RetardsNumber);//на случай ввода не числа не будет вылета - будет словно ввели 0
                if (RetardsNumber < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered zero/nonnumeric values as number of students. Programm execution is finished");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;
                }
                RetardedStudent[] Retards = new RetardedStudent[RetardsNumber];
                for (int i = 0; i < RetardsNumber; i++)//fill students and their scores
                {
                    Retards[i] = new RetardedStudent();
                    Console.Write("Input Name and score for student # {0} ", i + 1);
                    String StudentNameAndScore = Console.ReadLine();
                    int SpaceIndex = StudentNameAndScore.LastIndexOf(" ");
                    if (SpaceIndex != -1)
                    {
                        Retards[i].Name = StudentNameAndScore.Remove(SpaceIndex, StudentNameAndScore.Length - SpaceIndex);
                        Int32.TryParse(StudentNameAndScore.Remove(0, SpaceIndex + 1), out Retards[i].IQ);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Retards[i].Name = StudentNameAndScore;
                        Retards[i].IQ = 0;
                    }
                }
                if (RetardsNumber == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered 1 student " + Retards[0].Name + " with iq score test result: " + Retards[0].IQ + " Programm execution is finished because no need in sorting");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;
                }
                RetardedStudent tempRetard = new RetardedStudent();
                SortRetardedStudents(&Retards);

                for (int i = 0; i < RetardsNumber; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < RetardsNumber - i - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (Retards[j].IQ > Retards[j + 1].IQ || (Retards[j].IQ == Retards[j + 1].IQ) && (String.Compare(Retards[j].Name, 0, Retards[j + 1].Name, 0, Math.Max(Retards[j].Name.Length, Retards[j + 1].Name.Length)) > 0))
                        {
                            tempRetard.IQ = Retards[j].IQ;
                            tempRetard.Name = Retards[j].Name;
                            Retards[j].IQ = Retards[j + 1].IQ;
                            Retards[j].Name = Retards[j + 1].Name;
                            Retards[j + 1].IQ = tempRetard.IQ;
                            Retards[j + 1].Name = tempRetard.Name;
                        }

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("sorted by score then by Name");
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < RetardsNumber; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("# {0} ", i + 1);
                    Retards[i].PrintName();
                }
                //  Console.WriteLine("X format: {0:X}",99999);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            //
        }
    }
}
```

I try to call SortRetardedStudents but whatever i do i always encounter errors. I tried to use unsafe, i added property to project whicj allows me to run unsafe code. 
Right now my error is CS0208

Please help to solve the problem. I'm very bad with understanding pointers and references evem after videos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is no reason to use unsafe code here. 
It's looks like you miss `static` in your origin code.

```
public static void SortRetardedStudents(RetardedStudent[] Retards)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!